# can't import a magento database

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

i have a magento database which seems to be corrupted. so i want to repair it. but before i start repair i want to back up the existing database. but when i try to backup the database by exporting it and later try to import it, it gives errors like 
"#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' "

i simply can't take the backup. i tried copying the database from phpmyadmin as well but still same problem and there is no way i can take risk by attempting the repair on the existing database as it is being used in live website.

can anyone suggest what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It is not much of a Magento question, but more of a general export/import on a live site.
What I would suggest is to make export and then import to another clean database, and then rename the old one to "*_old" and new clean to the original name.

Of course, for some time the site would be down and there could be a little user sessions data lost, but if you tell your users about maintenance in advance, it shouldn't be a major problem.

Also what I would suggest is to test this approach on a localhost somewhere and only then on a live site. And of course, have all backups just in case.

Comment: as i said in my question i can export the database but i can't import it. whenever i try to import it to a new database it gives the error.

Comment: You mean, you import it to a *new clean* database? Not into a live one with data already in it?

Comment: no. i exported the live database and tried to import it to my localserver for testing. i created a new empty database and tried to import into it. but then i have the error when i import it. there seems to be a lot of duplicate data in the table.

Comment: I see, then I think there's no easy way of solving it :( 
You have to look for duplicate entries and somehow edit the data. Carefully.